# Shuffling words in a sentence in javascript (coding horror - How to improve?)

Tags: javascript, shuffle

I'm trying to do something that is fairly simple, but my code looks terrible and I am certain there is a better way to do things in javascript. I am new to javascript, and am trying to improve my coding. This just feels very messy.

All I want to do is to randomly change the order some words on a web page. In python, the code would look something like this:

```
s = 'THis is a sentence'
shuffledSentence = random.shuffle(s.split(' ')).join(' ')
```

However, this is the monstrosity I've managed to produce in javascript

```
//need custom sorting function because javascript doesn't have shuffle?
function mySort(a,b) {    
    return a.sortValue - b.sortValue;
}

function scrambleWords() {

    var content = $.trim($(this).contents().text());

    splitContent = content.split(' ');

    //need to create a temporary array of objects to make sorting easier
    var tempArray = new Array(splitContent.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < splitContent.length; i++) {
        //create an object that can be assigned a random number for sorting
        var tmpObj = new Object();
        tmpObj.sortValue = Math.random();
        tmpObj.string = splitContent[i];
        tempArray[i] = tmpObj;       
    }

    tempArray.sort(mySort);

    //copy the strings back to the original array
    for (i = 0; i < splitContent.length; i++) {
        splitContent[i] = tempArray[i].string;
    }

    content = splitContent.join(' ');       
    //the result
    $(this).text(content);      

}
```

Can you help me to simplify things?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost similar to the python code:

```
var s = 'This is a sentence'
var shuffledSentence = s.split(' ').shuffle().join(' ');
```

For the above to work, we need to add a shuffle method to Array (using [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)).

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var i = this.length;
    if (i == 0) return this;
    while (--i) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1 ));
        var a = this[i];
        var b = this[j];
        this[i] = b;
        this[j] = a;
    }
    return this;
};
```

Comment: I would simply return `this` if `i == 0`. Othwerwise the fluent interface will break.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.shuffler=function(delim){
    delim=delim || '';
    return this.split(delim).sort(function(){
            return .5-Math.random()}).join(delim);
}
```

// to shuffle words, pass a space

var s='abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz'
alert(s.shuffler(' '))

Comment: Good, but slower than Fisher-Yates.

Comment: -1 : using random values in a sort comparison function leads to improperly randomized lists since the sort relies on the fact that if a < b and b < c then a < c.  random numbers break this assumption and cause an uneven distribution of terms.

Answer (score 1):

This is very old question but can still be useful.
Here is a very easy way to do it using `array.sort()`

```js
const s = 'This is very old question but can still be useful.';

console.log(s.split(' ').sort(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3)) - 1).join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is untested, but it is a rough idea of an alternative approach:

```
function scrambleWords(text) {
  var words = text.split(' ');
  var result = "";

  while(words.length > 0) {
    if(result.length > 0) { words += " "; }
    words += words.splice(Math.abs(Math.random() * (words.length - 1)), 1);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Basically, the idea is to randomly splice words out of the origonal text and rebuild the string.

NOTE: splice is a little slow (rebuilds array), so if performance matters, I wouldn't suggest this as optimal, but I think the code is simplier.

UPDATE: I like the shuffle answer better that was just posted as a better solution :D

Comment: I don't think this code quite works, and if it did, it would still be a very slow and biased shuffle, which means each possible permutation would not be equally likely.

Answer (score 0):

**Using sort method and Math method :**

```
var arr =  ["HORSE", "TIGER", "DOG", "CAT"];
function shuffleArray(arr){
  return arr.sort( () => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3)) - 1)  
}

// every time it gives random sequence
shuffleArr(arr);
// ["DOG", "CAT", "TIGER", "HORSE"]
// ["HORSE", "TIGER", "CAT", "DOG"]
// ["TIGER", "HORSE", "CAT", "DOG"]
```