# Select random row from Safaris client-side database

Tags: sql, safari, mobile-safari

I'm experimenting with the built in SQL support in the Safari Browser and I want to select a random query via Javascript.

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY random()
```

Returns *not authorized to use function: random*

See [this screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/414562/Screen%20shot%202010-08-17%20at%2011.20.26%20AM.png).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Safari Web SQL Storage uses SQLite http://www.sqlite.org/

Answer (score 3):

Query using a non-random order, then shuffle the results:

```js
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM questions',[], function(tx, resultSet) {
    var resultArray = [];

    for(var i=0; i < resultSet.rows.length; i+=1) {
        resultArray.push(resultSet.rows.item(i));
    }

    var shuffledArray = shuffle(resultArray);

    // do something with the shuffled array...
});
```

Where `shuffle()` could be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/962890/490560

Comment: Alternatively, include underscorejs and use `_.shuffle()` or even `_.sample()`; the later gives you a random result of given length.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like the following would work:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT RANDOM() as RANDOM_NUM, Q.*
          FROM QUESTIONS Q)
  ORDER BY RANDOM_NUM
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but weirdly I get the same error again. not authorized to use function: random

Is this a security issue?

Comment: @user422644 - sure sounds that way.  Interestingly, this page (http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) at the SQLite site says that GRANT and REVOKE aren't supported so I'm not sure how one would work around this.  Wish I could offer more ideas.

Comment: Another way would be to shuffle the results after I got them.

  db.transaction(
     function(transaction) {
     transaction.executeSql(
       'SELECT * FROM questions',
       [],
       function (transaction, result) {
       // best way to shuffle results and loop?
       }, 
       errorHandler
     );
     },
     transactionErrorHandler
   );