# Math.random() and variable

Tags: jquery, random

how can i randomize for this variable one word?

```
var = 'stack';

for (i=0; i<5; i++){
   document.write( Math.random() ??? + '<br />');
}
```

sample result:

```
t
c
k
a
s
```

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943772/how-do-i-shuffle-the-characters-in-a-string-in-javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised as Neal pointed out that the previous solution does not take into account of duplicated letters:**

```
var randomIndexes = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    randomIndexes[i] = -1;
}

for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    while (randomIndexes[i] == -1) {
        randomIndexes[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length);
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (randomIndexes[i] == randomIndexes[j]) {
                randomIndexes[i] = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    document.write(word.charAt(randomIndexes[i]));
}
```

Comment: What if OP wants each letter to appear once?

Comment: @Thomas, the OP did not specify, and that code still seems to long even in that aspect

Comment: @Thomas, also your under the assumption that OP does not want to use a word like `glass` that has 2 `s`'s

Comment: @Neal Revised solution. Not the greatest solution but it will do.

Comment: @tox Probably just simple bugs. Go through the code and make sure you understand the concept.

Comment: @tox Try this revised solution again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
var st = 'stack';

for (i=0; i<st.length; i++){
    var random = (Math.random() * st.length);
    document.write( st.slice(random, random+1) + '<br />');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Xx4NA/ (keep pressing <kbd>Run</kbd> to see it run differently every time)

Comment: @Neal -- when I ran your fiddle I got the following: c
k
s
a
c

Comment: @ElGuapo, it is random, every `run` will have a different result

Comment: Right on.. yeah.. guess that makes sense... I thought @tox wanted each letter to show up, but randomized. Probably a bad assumption.

Comment: Is it suppose to be using individual chars more than once? Or is it suppose to merely shuffle the order of the chars?

Comment: @Jonathan, i am not the OP, i just went with what it looked like the answer was to the query

Comment: @Neal I was only asking since the OP's example appear to be a shuffling of the letters alone.

Comment: @Jonathan, i understand your question. i think we are all a bit thrown by the OP's example, but the OP said that that was a `sample result` which can mean there could be more results

Comment: @tox, pick one tho lol, stop goin back and forth, its making me dizzy