# Generate random integer with ALL digits from 1-9

Tags: javascript

How do I generate a 9-digit integer that has all digits from 1-9? Like 123456798, 981234765, 342165978, etc.

Doing this:

```
var min = 100000000;
var max = 999999999;
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

does not work give me the integer that I want most of the time (does not have ALL digits from 1 to 9).

111111119 is not acceptable because each number must have at least one "1" in it, "2", "3", ... and a "9" in it.

Comment: well for starters change the min to 111111111

Comment: That's not really random, is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just start with the string `123456789` and shuffle it randomly as described in [How do I shuffle the characters in a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943772/how-do-i-shuffle-the-characters-in-a-string-in-javascript)

```
String.prototype.shuffle = function () {
    var a = this.split(""),
        n = a.length;

    for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
    return a.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This program, with little tweaks, will be a good addition to your custom utility belt.

Adapted from the [`_.shuffle`](http://underscorejs.org/#shuffle) function of Underscore.js library, which shuffles the list of data with [Fisher-Yates Shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

```
function getRandomNumber() {
    var rand, index = 0, shuffled = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    shuffled.forEach(function(value) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ++index);
        shuffled[index - 1] = shuffled[rand];
        shuffled[rand] = value;
    });

    return shuffled.reduce(function(result, current) {
        return result * 10 + current;
    }, 0);
}

console.log(getRandomNumber());
```

This program will always return a number which has all the 9 numbers in it and the length is also 9.

Comment: Technically I don't think this is Fisher-Yates, as this does not shuffle in place.

Comment: @Peter You are correct, I updated the answer now, please check :)

Answer (score 1):

Recurse!

```
var randomize = function (str) {
    if (str.length == 9) return str;
    var newDigit = Math.floor(Math.random()*9 + 1);
    if (str.indexOf(newDigit) == -1) {
        return randomize(str + newDigit);
    } else {
        return randomize(str);
    }
}
```

There's a lot of room for optimisation there. Or just use a simple loop.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rYbPe/)