# Javascript Blogger scramble letters in title

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I have a blogger blog, and I would like the letters in the title of the blog to be scrambled every time the page is refreshed. If the title ot my blog was 'Cookies', I would want the header to show 'Ckooies' one time, and 'Ciekoos' the next for example, in a random fashion.

I'm currently looking at these  tags, assuming this is where I'll have to work the magic:

```
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title> 
<b:else/>
<title><data:blog.pageName/> ~ <data:blog.title/></title>
```

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Yes, I thought as much. I will add that to the original description.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I shuffle the characters in a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943772/how-do-i-shuffle-the-characters-in-a-string-in-javascript)