# JS: Array shuffling, not string shuffling

Tags: javascript, random, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle a string array using JS.  I hard-coded three sets of characters.  3 characters from each set were chosen at random and then concatenated.  So the concatenated string is 3 letters, followed by 3 numbers, followed by 3 symbols.  I want to shuffle this concatenated string so their order is randomized.

I already checked [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array), and my algorithm and code essentially matches what the second solution was, except for the fact that I have the shuffle loop in a bigger function (instead of as its own function). Perhaps I should add the shuffling to its own function and call it within the bigger function, but I think that will still give me the same result.

The "shuffling part" of the function isn't actually shuffling. When I debug it with console.log(temp) and console.log(tp[rnd]), the correct values are showing.  Basically, the function is returning the unshuffled string that I wanted to shuffle.

```
var letterSet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var numberSet = "0123456789";
var symbolSet = "~!@#$%^&*()-_+=><";

this.generatePassword = function() {
        var rl = "";
        var rn = "";
        var rs = "";
        var tp = "";

        // 3 random letters
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 52));
            rl += letterSet[rnd];
        }

        // 3 random numbers
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
            rn += numberSet[rnd];
        }

        // 3 random symbols
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 17));
            rs += symbolSet[rnd];
        }

        // String concatenation
        tp = rl + rn + rs;

        // Shuffling part
        for(var i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {
            var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * tp.length);
            var temp = tp[i];
            tp[i] = tp[rnd];
            tp[rnd] = temp;
        }

        return tp;
    }();
```

I don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shuffle is a bit off, I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943772/how-do-i-shuffle-the-characters-in-a-string-in-javascript) which uses an array to shuffle.

```
// String concatenation
tp = rl + rn + rs;
tp=tp.split('');

// Shuffling part
for(var i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {
   var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * tp.length);
   var temp = tp[i];
   tp[i] = tp[rnd];
   tp[rnd] = temp;
}
tp=tp.join("");
```

Comment: Well that did the trick.  Why is the 'split()' function necessary?

Comment: the split function makes an array from the string, so then the manipulation is using an array instead of a string, which isn't possible.

Comment: @daChi the `split` and `join` parts are necessary, because strings in javascript are immutable (as they are effectively values), while arrays are not.

Comment: Oh, so I was trying to shuffle a string when I thought I was shuffling an array.  Got it.

Comment: There are ways to manipulate the string without turning it into an array.  See my answer below.  @doldt

Answer (score 0):

When you perform the assignments `tp[i] = tp[rnd]` and `tp[rnd] = temp` it is not changing the value of `tp` because strings are immutable.  It is possible to manipulate a string and replace values using methods on `String`.  Change those two assignments to the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * tp.length);
    var temp = tp[i];
    tp = tp.replace(tp.substr(i, 1), tp[rnd]);
    tp = tp.replace(tp.substr(rnd, 1), temp);
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that technically, you're not mutating the string in this case either: a new string is created, which is assigned to the `tp` variable instead of the old one.

Comment: This is interesting as well... which way would you say is better?  Converting the string to an array, and then back to a string, or just doing string manipulations in and of itself?