# How to select a number of random elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var item = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
```

The code above selects a random item from the array. However, how could I get it to select 3 random elements from the array at once, rather than only one.

Rather than only selecting `three` for example, it should be something like `two five one`.

Comment: Do you want them to be different?

Comment: @Oriol Yes, I would like them to be different

Comment: first make an array to store selected items `var items=[]` then you can fill it in a loop, and as you select your item, also splice it from `array`, or you can use nested while loops, one checking if there's <3 elements in your items array, one checks if new item is already in it

Comment: Try adapting this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943985/145346

Answer (score 8):

You could use a dummy array for counting and a copy of the array and splice the random items without shuffling the array.

```js
var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
    result = array.slice(0, 3).map(function () { 
        return this.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length), 1)[0];
    }, array.slice());

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Always nice to see your solutions :)

Answer (score 3):

You can `shuffle()` the `array` and then get the first `X` items you need:

```js
var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var n = 3;
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length; i; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
    }
}
shuffle(array)
console.log(array.slice(0, 3))
```

The shuffle function was taken from this question: [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

If you still need the original `array` you can use `slice` it:

```js
var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var n = 3;
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length; i; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
    }
}
array_tmp = array.slice(0)
shuffle(array_tmp)
console.log(array_tmp.slice(0, 3))
console.log(array)
```