# How to shuffle the letters of a word using lua

Tags: lua, telegram-bot

I used this str_shuffle() function in PHP
and meka [this api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/papuI.png)
I need to do the same idea shuffle the letters With space between them but with lua 
 to working with telegram bots I searched a lot and found nothing similar

Comment: You could implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943772/how-do-i-shuffle-the-characters-in-a-string-in-javascript) in lua. I am going to try it, however, I don't know lua so it might take a little while.

Comment: Thanks man, waiting for you

Comment: I'm working on it, but it's hard and I had to do something first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
math.randomseed(os.time())

local function shuffle(str)
   local letters = {}
   for letter in str:gmatch'.[\128-\191]*' do
      table.insert(letters, {letter = letter, rnd = math.random()})
   end
   table.sort(letters, function(a, b) return a.rnd < b.rnd end)
   for i, v in ipairs(letters) do letters[i] = v.letter end
   return table.concat(letters)
end

print(shuffle("How to shuffle the whole UTF-8 string"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that does what you want with comments to explain how it works:

```
function tablelength(table) -- to calculate the length of a table
  local count = 0
  for _ in pairs(table) do count = count + 1 end -- loop through each of its items and add to a counter
  return count
end

function stringtoletters(text) -- split a string into its individual characters
  local letters = {}
  for a = 1, string.len(text) do -- loop through each character in the string and add it to the table
    table.insert(letters, string.sub(text, a, a))
  end
  return letters
end

function randomlyreorganizetext(text) -- the function that actually does the stuff AKA the meat
  local letters = stringtoletters(text)
  local n = tablelength(letters)

  math.randomseed(os.time()) -- initialize the random number generator
  math.random(); math.random(); math.random() -- the first few numbers are apparently not very random so get rid of them

  for i=n,1,-1 do -- go through each character and switch it out with another one of the of the characters at random
    local j = math.floor(math.random() * (i-1)) + 1 -- decide which character to swap with
    local tmp = letters[i] -- make a backup of the current value
    letters[i] = letters[j] -- change to random characters value
    letters[j] = tmp -- put what used to be the current value into the random characters position
  end

  return table.concat(letters, " ") -- turn the table back into a string and put spaces between each element
end

print(randomlyreorganizetext("hello"))
```

Comment: Call `math.randomseed` only once in your program, not in a library function.

Comment: Thanks man that's cool works like magic :) except there is a problem with Arabic letters does not work Can you help me with that

Comment: @Destroyer you should probably post another question because I don't know Lua and I think that is a problem with Unicode stuff and I don't know anything about that either.

Comment: @RaphaelFacredyn Thanks man yes because of the arabic letters string of length 2 , Thank you for everything and for your time very grateful to you ♥

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take. The first `gsub` indexes the letters in the string in the order they appear in it. Then we [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle)  the indices and use the shuffled indices to remap the letters with another `gsub`.

```
s="How to shuffle the letters of a word using lua"
t={}
n=0

s:gsub("%a",function (c)
        if t[c]==nil then
            n=n+1
            t[n]=c
            t[c]=n
        end
    end)

math.randomseed(os.time())
for i=n,2,-1 do
    local j=math.random(i)
    t[i],t[j]=t[j],t[i]
end

z=s:gsub("%a",function (c) return t[t[c]] end)
print(s)
print(z)
```

Comment: Now it works
But not with arabic words and also there is no spaces between letters

Comment: @Destroyer, for adding spaces, use `z=s:gsub("%a",function (c) return t[t[c]].." " end)`