# Shuffle and unscramble a string (Lua)

Tags: string, random, lua, shuffle

I have a function to shuffle strings from [another article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51754124/16701376) adapted to reorder the characters with a table of predefined numbers. It works perfectly, so I also needed a function to unscramble this string using the number table, but I have no idea how to do this, especially after having tried and failed several times.

Shuffle function:

```
randomValues = {} 
for i = 1, 60 do
   table.insert(randomValues, 1, math.random())
end
function shuffle(str)
   math.randomseed(4)
   local letters = {}
   local idx = 0
   for letter in str:gmatch'.[\128-\191]*' do
      idx = idx + 1
      table.insert(letters, {letter = letter, rnd = randomValues[idx]})
   end
   table.sort(letters, function(a, b) return a.rnd < b.rnd end)
   for i, v in ipairs(letters) do 
      letters[i] = v.letter
   end
   return table.concat(letters)
end
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume, that all you're trying to do is:

1. Split a string into unicode characters.
2. Shuffle these characters.
3. Restore the characters to their original position.

I have separated the splitting up of unicode characters and doing the actual shuffle, to make it a bit easier to follow.

### 1. Splitting the characters

Starting off with the splitting of characters:

```lua
-- Splits a string into a table of unicode characters.
local function splitLetters(str)
  local letters = {}
  for letter in str:gmatch'.[\128-\191]*' do
     table.insert(letters, letter)
  end
  return letters
end
```

This is mostly copied from the first part of your function.

### 2. Shuffling the table of characters

Now that we have a nice table of characters, that we can work with, it's time to shuffle them. Shuffling a list can be done by going through each character in order and swapping it with a randomly chosen (but still unshuffled) item. While we do that, we also keep a table of all indices that got swapped, which I call `swapTable` here.

```lua
-- Shuffles in place and returns a table, which can be used to unshuffle.
local function shuffle(items)
  local swapTable = {}
  for i = 1, #items - 1 do
    -- Swap the first item with a random item (including itself).
    local j = math.random(i, #items)
    items[i], items[j] = items[j], items[i]
    -- Keep track of each swap so we can undo it.
    table.insert(swapTable, j)
    -- Everything up to i is now random.
    -- The last iteration can be skipped, as it would always swap with itself.
    -- See #items - 1 at the top of the loop.
  end
  return swapTable
end
```

### 3. Restoring the letters to their original positions

Using this `swapTable`, it is now pretty straightforward to just do the whole shuffle again, but in reverse.

```lua
-- Restores a previous shuffle in place.
local function unshuffle(items, swapTable)
  -- Go through the swap table backwards, as we need to do everything in reverse.
  for i = #swapTable, 1, -1 do
    -- Do the same as before, but using the swap table.
    local j = swapTable[i]
    items[i], items[j] = items[j], items[i]
  end
end
```

### A full example using all those functions

Using those few functions (and `table.concat` to build up the list of letters into a string again) we can do everything you want:

```
-- Make our output reproducible
math.randomseed(42)

-- Split our test string into a table of unicode characters
local letters = splitLetters("Hellö Wörld! Höw are yoü?")

-- Shuffle them in-place, while also getting the swapTable
local swapTable = shuffle(letters)

-- Print out the shuffled string
print(table.concat(letters)) --> " rH?doröWüle Hl lwa eyöö!"

-- Unshuffle them in-place using the swapTable
unshuffle(letters, swapTable)

-- And we're back to the original string
print(table.concat(letters)) --> "Hellö Wörld! Höw are yoü?"
```

### Creating the swapTable upfront

In your example, you generate the `swapTable` upfront (and it also works slightly different for you). You can of course split that part out and have your `shuffle` function work similar to how `unshuffle` is currently implemented. Tell me, if you want me to elaborate on that.