# How to use Math.random() to distribute three pictures into three img elements?

Tags: javascript, math, random

I have 3 images. 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg. I want to distribute them into three `img` elements randomly (on window refresh, the three images' positions will change).
How do I use `Math.random()` here? Thanks.

```
<img src='' id='img1' />
<img src='' id='img2' />
<img src='' id='img3' />
```

Comment: Thanks, please forgive me, now I have done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are six different ways that the images can be put in the tags. Pick one of them using random:

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
var ids = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]][index];
document.getElementById('img'+ids[0]).src = '1.jpg';
document.getElementById('img'+ids[1]).src = '2.jpg';
document.getElementById('img'+ids[2]).src = '3.jpg';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can shuffle an array you create:

```
var arr = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"];
arr.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
```

[Some people prefer other ways of shuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling), but a shuffling method would work to ensure you get all of the elements only once in your resulting array.

Comment: Oh,thanks, I'm now reading the article of shuffling. shuffling is more difficult to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
```

But distribution won't be uniform.

Comment: Yes, I have read some articles, Math.random() just run for one item, not three...

Comment: You can run code multiple times, just write a function to replace number in img's src attribute.