# React - Update state of 2D array and fill it with random numbers using .map function and new Array.fill

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, nested, array.prototype.map

I'm working on a John Conway's Game of Life app and I'm still learning React.

[Here is what I have so far](http://fcc-game-of-life.surge.sh/). The game board is created using a 2D array in my `App.js`'s state. I use new Array and the .fill method in my constructor to initially create the squares of the board. Later on in `App.js` I have a function called isSquareAlive that handles the onClick functionality and changes the appropriate squares to a different color when the user clicks on them (they are "alive" in the Game of Life sense).

What I want to do now is generate a random board when the user first loads the app, some of the squares will be active and others will not. I have created a random number function called `getRandomNumber` that creates a 1 or 0. Now I want to create another function that will be called on componentDidMount and this function would create an initial game board when the user loads the app and it will call `getRandomNumber` and fill some of the 2d array's elements (squares) with 1's and others with 0's. Squares with 1's will be "alive" and squares with 0's won't.

In other words I want a randomly generated game board every time a user loads the page. How would I do this? Nested .map functions and then pushing the results of `getRandomNumber` into new Array.fill?

Here is my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import GameBoard from './GameBoard.js';
import Controls from './Controls.js';
import update from 'immutability-helper';
import Info from './Info.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      boardHeight: 50,
      boardWidth: 30,
      iterations: 10,
      reset: false,
      alive: false,
      board: [],
      randomNum: ''
    };

    this.state.board = new Array(this.state.boardHeight).fill(new Array(this.state.boardWidth).fill(0));
  }

  // Allows user to click button and change size of game board
  selectBoardSize = (width, height) => {
    this.setState({
      boardHeight: height,
      boardWidth: width,
      board: new Array(this.state.boardHeight).fill(new Array(this.state.boardWidth).fill(0))
    });
  }

  // Resets game board back to blank when user clicks reset button
  onReset = () => {
    this.setState({ board: new Array(this.state.boardHeight).fill(new Array(this.state.boardWidth).fill(0)) })
  }

  // Generates random number
  getRandomNumber = (max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  }

  /* This is the function I am trying to build and generate a random starting game board with
  componentDidMount = () => {
    // Stores random number 1 or 2
    const number = this.getRandomNumber(2);
    const data = this.state.board;

    // This is what I need help on
    const startingBoard = data.map((row, y) => {
                            row.map((ea, x) => {
                              return 1;
                            })
    })

    // After startingBoard is working I can set state with startingBoard
    this.setState({
      board: startingBoard
    });
  }
*/


  // Called when user clicks on specific square. Changes color of square depending on if it's alive or not
  isSquareAlive = (x, y) => {
    const data = this.state.board;
    const ySquare = y;
    const xSquare = x;

    const newData = data.map((row, y) => {
      return y === ySquare ? (
        row.map((cell, x) => x === xSquare ? (cell + 1) % 2 : cell)
      ) : (
        row
      )
    })

    this.setState({ board: newData });

  }



  render() {
    /*console.log('Random number is : ' + this.state.randomNum);*/
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="game-container">

      <GameBoard
        height={this.state.boardHeight}
        width={this.state.boardWidth}
        reset={this.onReset}
        board={this.state.board}
        alive={this.isSquareAlive}
        isAlive={this.state.alive}
      />

      <Controls
        selectBoardSize={this.selectBoardSize}
        iterations={this.state.iterations}
        onReset={this.onReset}
      />

      </div>

      <div className="info-container">
        <Info />
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The return 1 in `startingBoard` was just me being a noob and trying to get that to return something.

Just to reiterate: the board is created like this:

```
this.state.board = new Array(this.state.boardHeight).fill(new Array(this.state.boardWidth).fill(0));
```

How can I push random numbers into the 2D array?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified App. I think it may work to set the initial value for state.board in the constructor. This should effectively create a new board every time the user start the app.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const createRandomBoard = (height, width) => {

  const randomCellValue = () => (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 0);

  // thank you @simonbor on StackOverflow:
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836833/create-a-array-with-random-values-in-javascript
  const createRow = () => Array.from({length: width}, randomCellValue);

  return Array.from({length: height}, createRow);
};


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const boardHeight = 50;
    const boardWidth = 30;

    this.state = {
      boardHeight,
      boardWidth,
      board: createRandomBoard(boardHeight, boardWidth),
    };
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Sit this on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-gol-answer?file=App.js