# Assigning values whilst creating a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is some Javascript code that creates a 2-dimension array and fills each cell with a random number.

```js
// populate 2D array with integers
const row = 5, col = 7
let pic = new Array(row).fill(0).map(item => (new Array(col).fill(0)))
for (let x = 0; x < row; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < col; y++) {
    pic[x][y] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 90) + 10)
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(pic))
```

I'm looking for a more 'elegant' solution. My questions:

- Is there a way to use the `fill` so that I can put in my target values? Then I can be finished with creating the array in one line.
- How do I use a double `.map` to populate the 2D array, instead of a double `for` loop?
- Is there a way to assign the output from the `map` / `for` loops directly into a variable? Then I don't need a separate create statement.
- What is the best way to reshape an array? For example, changing a 1-by-10 array into a 5-by-2 array.
- Is there a way to enforce a type? For instance the first dimension is a string, 2nd is an integer, etc.

Feel free to add your own definition of elegance. One of the things I'm looking for is a flexible approach that can also work with 3D arrays.

Comment: what do you mean with the last point (type)?

Comment: I'm a user of strongly typed languages like Scala, where for instance, you could never store a string in an integer variable. I find the laissez faire of Javascript difficult.

Comment: The last 2 bullet points are completely different requirements. So, it's better to ask them in separate posts. [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223)

Comment: `I find the laissez faire of Javascript difficult.`  If this is the case there is https://www.typescriptlang.org/  or  maybe https://flow.org/

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Typescript and Flow. At the moment I'm investigating ReasonML. One day I'll post a question that clearly illustrates the benefits, when I find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the fill so that I can put in my target values? Then I can be finished with creating the array in one line.

No, `fill` is not that flexible. There is `Array.from(iterable, callback)` but I find it cumbersome and it is slow. I'd rather write that utility quickly

```
function array(n, callback){
  const output = Array(n);
  for(let i=0; i<n; ++i) output[i] = callback(i);
  return output;
}
```

> How do I use a double .map to populate the 2D array, instead of a double for loop?

`map` creates a new Array, by calling the callback function for each item on the current Array. You can abuse it to mutate the Array that is iterating. You can ignore the returnes Array and abuse it as `forEach`; but then `map` simply is the wrong tool.

```
var newMatrix = Array(5).fill().map(() => Array(7).fill().map(() => Math.random()));
```

the `fill` part is necessary, because `Array(length)` creates a sparse Array of that length and `map` only iterated defined indices *(even if they contain undefined)*

> Is there a way to assign the output from the map / for loops directly into a variable? Then I don't need a separate create statement.

I'm not sure what you mean, because you already do that here `let pic = new Array(row).fill(0).map(...)`

> What is the best way to reshape an array? For example, changing a 1-by-10 array into a 5-by-2 array.

```js
function array(n, callback) {
  const output = Array(n);
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) output[i] = callback(i);
  return output;
}

function toGroupsOf(n, data) {
  return array(Math.ceil(data.length / n), i => data.slice(n * i, n * (i + 1)));
}

const oneByTen = [array(10, v => v)];
console.log(oneByTen);

const twoByFive = toGroupsOf(5, oneByTen.slice().flat());
console.log(twoByFive);
```

> Is there a way to enforce a type? For instance the first dimension is a string, 2nd is an integer, etc.

No, not in JS. *btw. everything but the last dimension will be Arrays, not String.*

But check out [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

> Feel free to add your own definition of elegance. One of the things I'm looking for is a flexible approach that can also work with 3D arrays.

```js
// a general purpose function to create n-dimensional arrays.
// m(...dimensions, (...indices) => value)
function m(...args) {
  return args.reduceRight((cb, length) => (...indices) => {
    const output = Array(length);
    for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i)
      output[i] = cb(...indices, i);
    return output;
  })();
}

let data = m(5,7, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10));
console.log(data);

// 4-dimensions
console.log(m(2,3,4,5, Math.random));

// a 5x5 identity-matrix
console.log(m(5,5, (i,j) => i === j? 1: 0).join("\n"));
```

> I'm a user of strongly typed languages like Scala, where for instance, you could never store a string in an integer variable. I find the laissez faire of Javascript difficult.

I have mixed opinions on that. I loved the way that static types and compile-time errors found little mistakes/oversights back when I learned (in AS3). Nowadays and with Typescript I often find Typescript to be too opinionated and find myself thinking f off compiler, I know/mean what I'm writing here and prefer the flexibility of JS. On the other hand, I still enjoy the assistance that comes from the IDE knowing what Objects I'm currently dealing with and what properties/methods they provide.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a nested [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a length and a mapping function.

```js
const
    fn = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
    row = 5,
    col = 7,
    array = Array.from({ length: row }, () => Array.from({ length: col }, fn));

array.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Answer (score 1):

Heavily inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859978/9758920

```js
const row = 5, col = 7;

let pic = [...Array(row)].map(r => [...Array(col)].map(c => ~~(Math.random()*90)+10));

console.log(pic)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
const randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*90)+10);
const randomMatrix = (row, col) => {
    return new Array(row).fill(randomNumber).map(item => (new Array(col).fill(randomNumber))) 
}

console.log(randomMatrix(5, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet below.  `initializeArray` accepts parameters for `width`, `height` and a `value` for each cell.

```js
const initialize2DArray = (w, h, val = null) =>
  Array.from({ length: h }).map(() => Array.from({ length: w }).fill(val));

console.log(initialize2DArray(3, 3, 0)) // 3x3 matrix filled with zeros
```

If you prefer a **N-dimension** array, try the snippet below:

```js
const initializeNDArray = (val, ...args) =>
  args.length === 0
    ? val
    : Array.from({ length: args[0] }).map(() => initializeNDArray(val, ...args.slice(1)));
    
console.log(initializeNDArray(-1, 3, 3, 3))
```