# Is there a method to fill the array with random numbers without repeating in React Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, random

I need to create an array from 0 to 60, where numbers will not repeat. Is there a method to do this in React Native?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836833/create-an-array-with-random-values

Answer (score 1):

You can create array with number then randomize them

```
const generateArr = (n) => {
    const arr = []
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        arr.push(i) 
    }
    return arr
}
```

Then you can randomize array with one of the methods described here:
[How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)