# What is the purpose of subtracting from Math.random?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, math

I'm going through javascript.info and doing the practice tasks for Array Methods. This one is "Shuffle an array" and the instructions are:

> *Write the function shuffle(array) that shuffles (randomly reorders) elements of the array.*

I couldn't figure it out so I looked it up but now im struggling to understand it. **What does the ".5 -" do in the line `.5 - Math.random`?**

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

function shuffle(array) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => .5 - Math.random())
}
console.log(shuffle(arr))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.sort` callback will iterate over the elements of the array and sort them depending on the value returned by the callback. If a negative number is returned, `a` will be sorted before `b` - if a positive number is returned, `b` will be sorted before `a`.

`Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1. If it's subtracted from 0.5, you get a random number between -0.5 and +0.5. So doing

```
(a, b) => .5 - Math.random()
```

is a way to get the callback to return a positive number 50% of the time and a negative number 50% of the time, and will randomly shuffle the array *to a certain extent*.

That said, "sorting" in this manner will [produce biased results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70014953). Use [a better algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976).

Comment: I see. Thank you for taking the time to help me out!
So if I were to do `(a, b) => .25 - Math.random()` this would return a positive number 75% of the time, returning the same 3 digit sequence pattern 75% of the time, correct? (I understand this isn't helpful for my use case).
I tested it in JSFiddle and this seems to be the case, as it returned [1, 2, 3] about 75% of the time.