# How to get random elements from an array

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Getting random value from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/javascript-getting-random-value-from-an-array)

```
var numbers = new Array('1','2','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
```

I have a JavaScript Array and now want to randomly choose four different numbers from it and then express it on the page (through `document.write`). Obviously each time the page is reloaded by the user it would show four different random numbers.

Comment: OT: It is better practices to use array literals: `var numbers = ['1', ...];`.

Comment: Actually this is not the same question as the supposed duplicate: getting more than one, different, properly random value from an array is significantly more complicated than just getting one random value.

Comment: @TimDown: Agreed. If this would be the same question as the supposed duplicate the answer(s) would be the same (same questions have same answers right?) which clearly are not.

Comment: The following is a closer duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935175/sampling-a-random-subset-from-an-array

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could shuffle the array and pick the first four.

```
numbers.sort( function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() } );
```

Now `numbers[0]`, `numbers[1]`... and so on have random and unique elements.

Note that this method may not be an optimal way to shuffle an array: see [Is it correct to use JavaScript Array.sort() method for shuffling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling) for discussion.

Comment: Nice one! Good point taking the unique-elements into account.

Comment: It hardly matters in this circumstance, but I find it interesting all the same; this method turns out not-to-be-so-random after all: http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-fix-their-non-random-browser-choice-screen/

Comment: @Matt Good point, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: This also changes the original array, which may be undesirable.

Comment: Or `number.filter(() => Math.round(Math.random())` to get random items and continue with sort in case it's needed.

Answer (score 25):

If you want this to be as random as the native implementations of JavaScript's `Math.random()` will allow, you could use something like the following, which also has the advantages of leaving the original array untouched and only randomizing as much of the array as required:

```
function getRandomArrayElements(arr, count) {
    var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, min = i - count, temp, index;
    while (i-- > min) {
        index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
        temp = shuffled[index];
        shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = temp;
    }
    return shuffled.slice(min);
}


var numbers = ['1','2','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
alert( getRandomArrayElements(numbers, 4) );
```

Comment: By far the best answer I have come across (for my needs at least), thank you

Comment: Actually random, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
//return a random integer between 0 and 10

document.write(Math.floor(Math.random()*11));
```

Comment: I assumed that "four different numbers" means that the numbers have to be unique.

Comment: Or `document.write( numbers[ (Math.floor(Math.random()*11) ] ] );` which becomes increasingly important if the numbers array doesn't contain something as trivial as 1-10.

Comment: I didn't as it says everytime page is loaded it should be random.

Comment: @Nim Could be both ways, but I interpreted that part so that each page load should pull different (but unique) random numbers, not the sames that were shown the last time.

Answer (score 3):

```
var numbers = new Array('1','2','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
document.write(numbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length)]);
```