# jQuery (or JS) How to make a Randomized New Array From an existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Say I had

```
 var imgs = ["pItem1","pItem2","pItem3","pItem4","pItem5"]
```

How can get a new array from the current one, that randomly picks lets say 3 items from the old array and puts it in a new array.

```
var newArray =["pItem1," "pItem4," "pItem2"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're basically looking to take a randomly sampled subset of an array. One approach is to randomly shuffle the array, then take a slice from the beginning of the array. See this implementation of `getRandomSubarray()` in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11935263/2943575

Comment: If you're just going to link to another question, you should flag this as a duplicate, not post an answer with a link to the other question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/npvo6h9d/
this might help.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, wasn't sure of the best way to reference an existing answer.

Comment: Thank you joe and wlin. I have solved my problem.