# indexOf / includes don't do an exact match and return false positives

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof, qualtrics

I want to build an if statement in which the *if* criteria is based on an equality test of whether a variable equals **any** of several values. However, I do not want to hardcode the test values, but to pass an array of values that had been randomly subset earlier.

**First**, I get the set of randomized values by subsetting/sampling 5 values out of an array of 15 values. Basically, I'm using [this excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11935263/6105259).

```js
function getRandomSubarray(arr, size) {
    var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, temp, index;
    while (i--) {
        index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
        temp = shuffled[index];
        shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = temp;
    }
    return shuffled.slice(0, size);
}

var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
var fiveRandomMembers = getRandomSubarray(x, 5);
```

**Then**, I want to pass `fiveRandomMembers` to test whether a variable is equal to any of the values in `fiveRandomMembers`'s array. Then do something. To this end, I want to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728585/6105259).

```js
var L = function()
{
    var obj = {};
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
        obj[arguments[i]] = null;

    return obj;
};

if(foo in L(fiveRandomMembers)) {
/// do something
};
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I must admit that the implementation of this code is within a Qualtrics survey, so the problem **might be** nuanced to the Qualtrics platform, and that's the reason it isn't working for me. I'm newbie to JavaScript so I apologize if this is a trivial question. But I believe that my code is problematic even in plain JavaScript (that is, regardless of Qualtrics), and I want to figure out why.

### UPDATE 2020-05-24

I've been digging into this more deeply, and I have some insights. This looks more like a qualtrics problem rather than plain JS issue. However, the underlying problem might still have to do with some JS mechanism, and that's why I bother to update it here -- maybe someone will know what's causing this behavior.

To recap -- I want to condition an action based on whether a given variable's content matches *either* of the values in an array. I've tried using both `includes` and `indexOf`, but either method fails. The problem boils down to the functions not doing an **exact** match. For example, if I have an array of 5 numbers such as `8, 9, 12, 13, 14`, and I want to test whether `4` exists in the array, then an exact match should return `FALSE`. However, both `indexOf` and `contains` return `TRUE` because `14` has `4` in it. This is not an exact matching then. Furthermore, I've tried to investigate what is the position `indexOf` would return for such a false-positive match. Typically, it would return a position that is even larger than the total length of the array, making no sense whatsoever. Here's an example from my Qualtrics survey, demonstrating the problem:

[image: qualtrics]

The code giving this is comprised of two qualtrics questions:

**(-) First piece**

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/

    function getRandomSubarray(arr, size) {
    var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, temp, index;
    while (i--) {
        index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
        temp = shuffled[index];
        shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = temp;
    }
    return shuffled.slice(0, size);
}

var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
var fiveRandomMembers = getRandomSubarray(x, 5);

if (Array.isArray(fiveRandomMembers)) Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('is_array', "TRUE");


Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('length', fiveRandomMembers.length);


Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('five_sampled_numbers', fiveRandomMembers);

});
```

**(-) Second piece**

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    jQuery("#"+this.questionId).find('.QuestionText:first').css("padding-bottom", "0px");


var currentLoopNum = "${lm://CurrentLoopNumber}";
    // var currentLoopNum = parseInt(currentLoopNum, 10); // tried converting to numeric but it doesn't solve the problem
var fiveSampledNumbers = "${e://Field/five_sampled_numbers}";

if (fiveSampledNumbers.includes(currentLoopNum)) {
   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('does_loop_number_appear', "Yes");
} else {
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('does_loop_number_appear', "No");

}
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('index_of', fiveSampledNumbers.indexOf(currentLoopNum));

});
```

**Here is a link to the Qualtrics survey, demonstrating the problem, in case it's helpful for troubleshooting**: [link](https://hujipsych.au1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_ctDdiCosrP9cc8R)

---

**However,** when testing the same code outside of Qualtrics, the problem doesn't replicate.

[image: js_testing]

Does someone have a clue or even a hypothesis what could be the problem with the matching? Even if you're not necessarily familiar with Qualtrics...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the qualtrics site so we can test for ourselves?

Comment: Also, would be nice if you'd include the code used in the qualtrics screenshot.

Comment: @marco-a, thanks -- I updated the post with JS code and provided a link to the Qualtrics survey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never worked with Qualtrics before, but to me it is clear that the line

```js
var fiveSampledNumbers = "${e://Field/five_sampled_numbers}";
```

will assign a string value to `fiveSampledNumbers`, not an array value.

Indeed, if you attempt to run the checks you are making on a string rather than an array, you get the unexpected results you saw above, because you are doing string operations rather than array operations:

```js
var fiveSampledNumbers = "6,4,10,11,15";
console.log(fiveSampledNumbers.includes(5));  // logs true (string ends with the character "5")
console.log(fiveSampledNumbers.indexOf(5));   // logs 11   (index of the character "5")
```

To get around this, you will have to split the string by commas and parse each number within it:

```js
var fiveSampledNumbers = "6,4,10,11,15";
fiveSampledNumbers = fiveSampledNumbers.split(",").map(function (n) { return parseInt(n, 10); });
console.log(fiveSampledNumbers.includes(5));  // logs false
console.log(fiveSampledNumbers.indexOf(5));   // logs -1
```

Comment: A-ha! I see. Is there a way to reconstruct the parsed set of numbers as an array? Or otherwise directly convert the original string to array?

Comment: @Emman: the second line of the last snippet of code does exactly that.