# Drawing numbers from the array of numbers without returning them to the array

Tags: javascript

I want to draw 3 numbers from the array

```
let num = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
```

but after drawing each of them, the chosen number should be removed from the num array.

For e.g. `0` is chosen, the next two can be drawn from

```
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
```

and so on.

Does anyone know how to do that in the most efficient way?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be specific to [tag:angular] _or_ [tag:typescript]. Don't you just want to pick randomly from a [tag:javascript] array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sampling a random subset from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935175/sampling-a-random-subset-from-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.splice()` does exactly that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

console.log("arr: " + arr);

let removed = arr.splice(0,1);

console.log("removed: " + removed);
console.log("arr: " + arr);

removed = arr.splice(4,3);

console.log("removed: " + removed);
console.log("arr: " + arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove multiple indices from an array, you need to remove them in reverse numerical order so that the act of removing each item does not disturb the positions of elements before it in the array.

```js
let num = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

let indices = [2,0,3]

let result =
  [...indices].sort((a,b)=>b-a)
  .reduce((a,c)=>(a.unshift(...num.splice(c,1)),a),[])

console.log(result)
console.log(num)
```