# jquery get the unreapeatable values

Tags: javascript

i have a array with numbers. i need that array value to be generated once i click on the button, while i click on the button i need to get the value random wise from the array, but the value should not be repeated.

ex, if i get a 2 from out of 5, then i should not get the 2 again. for this i wrote this function, but the values are repeating... any idea?

```
var ar = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*ar.length);
ar.splice(ran,1);
alert(ar.splice);
```

the array values should not be removed. because if i click the button again, i need to get the values like before.

i did my work like this : but the rand values are repeating, any one can correct this to get unrepeatable values to get?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
        var mySize = 5;
        x = 0;
        while(mySize>=1){
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*mySize);
            mySize--;
            alert(rand);
        }

    })
```

Comment: Shuffle your array. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling/962890#962890

Answer (score 1):

You need your array to be in an outer scope for this like:

```
(function(){
    var ar = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
    document.getElementById('thebutton').onclick = function(){
        alert(ar.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*ar.length), 1));
    };
})();
```

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/25jXb/)

If you create your array inside the onclick function then you are just recreating the entire array every time the button is clicked.

Comment: I need the all array values to be shuffled, and the alert need to show the shuffled values. as well the shuffled values should not keep the repetatives. ex: [0,2,3,5,4,4] or like that..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this demo. In this it randomizes the array values and will repeat only after all the values are utilized.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MbkwK/1/)**

Based on the update in your question here it is take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/MbkwK/2/

Comment: My solution wrks exactly, take a look.

Comment: it generates only one number per click, it should  not like that, i need all the elements from the array shuffled. without repeating one..

Answer (score 0):

```
var ar = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
document.getElementById('thebutton').onclick = function() {
    var shuffle = [];
    var copyarr = ar.slice(0);
    var arlength = copyarr.length;
    for (i = 0; i < arlength; i++) {
        shuffle.push(copyarr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * copyarr.length), 1));
    }
    alert(shuffle.join(","));
};
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/qLSud/1/