# Most efficient array shuffler

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle, performance

How can I shuffle an array's values in the most efficient manner possible?

Each element is just a string containing HTML.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling).

Comment: http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_317-array-shuffle-function This has some smallish codes

Comment: http://sedition.com/perl/javascript-fy.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few choices.

First, you could use the *stupidely naïve* sorter...

```
arr = arr.sort(function() {
    return Math.random() - .5
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bksNb/).

This is quick and dirty but often considered bad practice.

[Further Reading](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/blog/2010/mar/09/microsoft-browser-ballot-reshuffle-code).

The *best* way to randomly sort an `Array` is with the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

```
var newArr = [];

while (arr.length) {

   var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length),
       element = arr.splice(randomIndex, 1)

   newArr.push(element[0]);       

}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uyusip/edit#javascript).

Comment: How come you gave me a jsfiddle link for the one `"often considered bad practice"` and not the Fisher-Yates shuffle?

Comment: @Adam Just writing the Fisher Yates now and had to look it up :)

Comment: It's ok. I'll use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling/#answer-962890

Comment: OpenDNS: `"Phishing Site Blocked
Phishing is a fraudulent attempt to get you to provide
personal information under false pretenses."`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3182/discussion-between-adam-lynch-and-alex)

Comment: `splice` is extremely slow compared to `pop`. see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65637626/633183) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Let me post my own answer just to encourage you **NOT TO** use random `sort()` method as it will produce *not so random* output.

As being said, [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is the most [efficient](https://jsperf.com/shuffle-contest/18) algorithm for that purpose, and it can be easily implemented with the following ES6 code:

```js
const src = [...'abcdefg'],

      shuffle = arr => arr.reduceRight((r,_,__,s) => 
        (r.push(s.splice(0|Math.random()*s.length,1)[0]), r),[])

console.log(JSON.stringify(shuffle(src)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the one I use. It gives a random number to each element, sorts the array by those random numbers (moving the real values along) and then removes the random numbers again. It seems to be equally distributed, but I've not mathematically proven it yet.

```
arr = arr.map(function(v) {
    return [v, Math.random()];
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
}).map(function(v) {
    return v[0];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XQRFt/ - Test results (might be slow)

Comment: This relies on ECMAScript 5 `Array` methods, which rules out IE < 9.

Comment: @Tim Down: Yes, you're correct. In fact, those functions tend to be inefficient in terms of speed too. But personally I find it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to shuffle an array:

```
    function shuffle(array) {
       var resultArray = new Array();
       for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
           var randomEle = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
           resultArray.push(array[randomEle]);
           array.splice(randomEle,1);
       }
       resultArray = resultArray.concat(array);
       return resultArray;
    }
```

This is a shuffle contest to compare my method with the other 2

http://jsperf.com/shuffle-contest/2

Comment: I've added the Fisher-Yates shuffle from @alex's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7309413/727074) to your jsPerf ['contest'](http://jsperf.com/shuffle-contest/3). It's the fastest

Comment: @AdamLynch : and I have added [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749849/11299053), so, let me [grab](https://jsperf.com/shuffle-contest/18) the prize for the modern, perfectly balanced (performance - conciseness) solution