# JavaScript - Understanding the role of a variable in a function passed as an argument

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to work with **regular expressions**, in particular I've to **shuffle the middle content of a string**. I found an example that fits my needs [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146283/mixing-up-the-middle-of-strings-in-javascript) and the answer I'm studying is the one by Brian Nickel.

This is the code proposed by Brian Nickel in the question:

```
myStr.replace(/\b([a-z])([a-z]+)([a-z])\b/ig, function(str, first, middle, last) {
return first +
       middle.split('').sort(function(){return Math.random()-0.5}).join('') + 
       last;
});
```

I'm very beginner in JavaScript and RegEx, I see here a function is passed as an argument, but I don't understand why there are four parameters, in particular I do not understand the first parameter `str` and why if I remove it, function doesn't work anymore correctly.

I now it's a silly question, but I don't found what I want on the Web, or maybe I don't know how to search properly. Thanks in advance

Comment: See the documentation, the function is explained for example here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using replace with RegExp, the function use as callback receive 1+n parameters where `n` are the match inside parenthesis.

The always come in that order :

1. The complete matched string.
2. The first parenthesis.
3. The second parenthesis.
4. Go on...

If you remove the `str` and the argument `first` become the matched string. So even if you don't use this argument, you need it!