# javascript to generate 50 no-repeat random numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript to generate  50 no-repeat random numbers and the number is in the range 1 to 50.how can I realize it?The 50 numbers stored in a array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First generate an ordered list:

```
var i, arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    arr[i] = i + 1;
}
```

then shuffle it.

```
arr.sort(function () {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
});
```

I tested the above method and it performed well. However, the ECMAScript spec does not require `Array.sort` to be implemented in such a way that this method produces a truly randomized list - so while it might work now, the results could potentially change without warning. Below is an implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle, which is not only guaranteed to produce a reasonably random distribution, but is faster than a hijacked sort.

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var p, n, tmp;
    for (p = array.length; p;) {
        n = Math.random() * p-- | 0;
        tmp = array[n];
        array[n] = array[p];
        array[p] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has a minor bug since i starts from 1. Use array's `push` method instead to add element to it. http://jsfiddle.net/KUfcf/

Comment: Thanks, fixed (before the comment actually). `push` is slightly slower than a direct assignment, so (in this case) I think it's better to use `[i]`.

Comment: The solution you provided works perfectly.Thanks

Comment: [That's doesn't generate uniformly random arrangements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/962802/102441)

Comment: @Eric I wouldn't say that, but rather, that it is not required to produce uniformly random arrangements. But thanks for the comment and especially the link; answer edited to include a true sort.