# Percentage chance of saying something?

Tags: javascript, random

I want to write a program that:

- 80% of the time will say `sendMessage("hi");`
- 5% of the time will say `sendMessage("bye");`
- and 15% of the time will say `sendMessage("Test");`

Does it have to do something with `Math.random()`?
like

```js
if (Math.random() * 100 < 80) {
  sendMessage("hi");
}
else if (Math.random() * 100 < 5) {
  sendMessage("bye");
}
```

Comment: hmmm ... that adds up to 145%.

Comment: it's possible, if you look at it as if he has three chances to say something or nothing; once 90%, once 50% and once 5%

Comment: its definetly not impossible , its like a scrolling add that give greater priority to certain ads, you could do something like an array where there are 100 items , 40 are a, 30 are b , and 30 are c , then randomly choose one, just not 90%, 50%, and 5% - rethink your math

Comment: @Tom: as in, it is possible for it to say "hi bye test"? The code uses `else if`, not a simple `if`, so I doubt that's a real option, but still, good catch.

Comment: now that it no longer says 145%, either the solutions below that suggest calling random once and using the result would be the way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yes, `Math.random()` is an excellent way to accomplish this. What you want to do is compute a single random number, and then make decisions based on that:

```
var d = Math.random();
if (d < 0.5)
    // 50% chance of being here
else if (d < 0.7)
    // 20% chance of being here
else
    // 30% chance of being here
```

That way you don't miss any possibilities.

Comment: The key point to make is that you should generate and use ONE random number.

Comment: why'd you put the word "double"

Comment: @user2537537 -- the first line declares (and defines) a Java double-precision floating-point variable; that's just the correct Java syntax for declaring a variable.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't it be "<= 0.5" instead of "< 0.5", because how it is now is 49% chance, not 50%.

Comment: @DysanixOfficial  Not 49% -- more like 49.999999999... which, as any mathematician can tell you, is pretty much 50%. But sure -- <= would be correct too.

Comment: Why is it that when I google "coin flip in javascript" it says run this code: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0` to determine if its heads. Doesn't your code do the same thing in a simpler manner? I.e., `Math.random() < 0.5`?

Comment: @Ogen Indeed. Perhaps there is something special about JavaScript that makes the longer form preferable, but in Java, certainly, it would be ridiculous.

Comment: @DysanixOfficial it should be < .5, because random can return 0, but cannot return 1. When you write <= .5, you're defining these ranges:
(0 ; .5) and (0.5+0.(1) ; 0.(9) ). So you have 0.500...01% for true and 0.4999...9% for false

Comment: better (and more generic) soluion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437797/pick-item-from-list-at-random-each-has-different-chance

Comment: @Ogen perhaps that's because multiplying by 2 is a simple bit-wise left shift operation and Floor is a simple truncation. I think decimal numbers could be relatively expensive

Comment: @Sgene9 but random() returns a double between 0 and 1 — multiplying by 2 is a floating-point operation

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I'm making a guess based on possible low-level operations. Floating point numbers can be represented by bits and be bit shifted.
0.75(base of 10) -> 0.11(2) -> do bitshift -> 1.1(2) -> 1.5(10)

Answer (score 23):

For cases like this it is usually best to generate *one* random number and select the case based on that single number, like so:

```
int foo = Math.random() * 100;
if (foo < 80) // 0-79
    sendMessage("hi");
else if (foo < 85) // 80-84
    sendMessage("bye");
else // 85-99
    sendMessage("test");
```

Answer (score 5):

I made a percentage chance function by creating a pool and using the fisher yates shuffle algorithm for a completely random chance. The snippet below tests the chance randomness 20 times.

```js
var arrayShuffle = function(array) {
   for ( var i = 0, length = array.length, swap = 0, temp = ''; i < length; i++ ) {
      swap        = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      temp        = array[swap];
      array[swap] = array[i];
      array[i]    = temp;
   }
   return array;
};

var percentageChance = function(values, chances) {
   for ( var i = 0, pool = []; i < chances.length; i++ ) {
      for ( var i2 = 0; i2 < chances[i]; i2++ ) {
         pool.push(i);
      }
   }
   return values[arrayShuffle(pool)['0']];
};

for ( var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
   console.log(percentageChance(['hi', 'test', 'bye'], [80, 15, 5]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const t = 10; // time in seconds
const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (t + 1));
if (a > 8) {
    // 20% chance code
} else {
    // 80% chance code
}
```

It has +1 as `Math.random()` and `Math.floor()` lower the maximum by 1 when put together.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a 20% chance to get "Yupiii!" in the console.log

```
const testMyChance = () => {

  const chance = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)[0]

  if(chance) console.log("Yupiii!")
  else console.log("Oh my Duck!")
}

testMyChance()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling

Answer (score 0):

In the situation when you need to achieve exactly the percentage for each item, you can create an array with exact number of items and remove one random item at a time from the array:

```js
const items = [
  {
    name: "hi",
    num: 80
  },
  {
    name: "bye",
    num: 5
  },
  {
    name: "test",
    num: 15
  }
];

const chances = [];
// fill chances array with specified number of each item
for(const item of items)
{
  chances.push(...new Array(item.num).fill(item));
}

// randomize the array
// alternatively we can leave the array intact and
// randomely remove an item with:
// const [item] = chances.splice(~~(Math.random() * chances.length - 1), 1);
for (let i = chances.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
  const r = ~~(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  [chances[i], chances[r]] = [chances[r], chances[i]];
}

//test
const count = {};
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  const item = chances.pop();

  count[item.name] = count[item.name] + 1 || 1; //count how many times an item was picked;
  console.log(item.name, count[item.name], "of", item.num);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:unset!important;overflow:auto!important;}
```

And here is a little class that will automatically regenerate the array once each item satisfied number of times it was be picked.

```js
class RandomItem
{
  constructor (list)
  {
    this.chances = [];
    this.list = list;
  }

  get item()
  {
    if (!this.chances.length)
    {
      for(const item of this.list)
        this.chances.push(...new Array(item.num).fill(item));
    }

    return this.chances.splice(~~(Math.random() * this.chances.length - 1), 1)[0];
  }
}


//test
const random = new RandomItem([
  {
    name: "hi",
    num: 8
  },
  {
    name: "bye",
    num: 2
  },
  {
    name: "test",
    num: 5
  }
]);

const count = {};
//note we are doing more iterations than sum of all item numbers
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
   const item = random.item;

  count[item.name] = count[item.name] + 1 || 1; //count how many times an item was picked;
  console.log(item.name, count[item.name], "of", item.num);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:unset!important;overflow:auto!important;}
```

Answer (score -2):

Java

```
/**
 * Zero or less returns 'false', 100 or greater returns 'true'. Else return probability with required percentage.
 * @param percentage for example 100%, 50%, 0%.
 * @return true or false with required probability.
 */
private static boolean probably(int percentage) {
    double zeroToOne = Math.random(); // greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0
    double multiple = zeroToOne * 100; // greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 100.0
    return multiple < percentage;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function probably(percentage) {
  return Math.random() * 100 < percentage;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this package

[chance-percent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chance-percent)

```js
import { random } from 'chance-percent';

const options = [
  {value: 1, percentage: 10},
  {value: 3, percentage: 60},
  {value: 2, percentage: 30},
]

const value = random(options);
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a very simple approximate solution to the problem. Sort an array of true/false values randomly and then pick the first item.

This should give a 1 in 3 chance of being true..

```
var a = [true, false, false]
a.sort(function(){ return Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 1 : -1 })[0]
```

Comment: Array.prptotype.sort may call the sort function more than once with the same arguments. If you want the probability to be exactly 1/3 you need to make your sort function idempotent.

Comment: @chris-browne I did say that it's an "approximates solution" but I will make the fix so that it's closer to 1/3. Thanks for the input.