# Javascript shuffle function returns same value in for loop

Tags: javascript

Why do I get three arrays in the same order while I shuffle them with a shuffle function in a for loop?

```
var items = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b'];
var createSlots = function(slots) 
{
    slots = slots || 3;
    var slotRack = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < slots; i++ )
    {
        slotRack.push(shuffle(items));
    }
    return slotRack;
}

function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};

var slotmachine = createSlots();  

// returns three arrays with values in the same order... do not want that... :(
console.log(slotmachine);
```

Comment: You're always mutating the same Array object. You need to make a copy if you want each result to hold a unique set of values. `slotRack.push(shuffle(items.slice())`

Comment: Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`squint` stated your problem in a comment above.

Anyway, here's a cooler shuffle method that will always get you out of trouble:

```
function shuffle(arr) {
    return arr.sort(function () {
        return Math.random() - Math.random()
    });
};
```

**EDIT** (thank's `Mr. Llama`):

Use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling/962829#962829)(thanks to `Christoph` for the implementation) instead:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var tmp, current, top = array.length;

    if(top) while(--top) {
        current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
        tmp = array[current];
        array[current] = array[top];
        array[top] = tmp;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Nonononono, don't *ever* use `sort` with `Math.random()` to shuffle an array.  The result [**is not random**](http://sroucheray.org/blog/2009/11/array-sort-should-not-be-used-to-shuffle-an-array/).  Use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/962829/477563) instead.

Comment: @Mr.Llama - Didn't know that - Thanks for you referral. I also updated my post to prevent future misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing in a reference to the same array in every iteration of the loop, try this instead:

```
 slotRack.push(shuffle(items.slice()));
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crrcq027/)

Edit: Maybe its better to do the `slice()` in your function, so return `o.slice()` and you don't have to worry about it when using the function.

Comment: Thanks guys, is using the slice() function to lose the reference a common practice?