# Change Image Angular-UI Carousel

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-carousel

I have created an Angular-UI Carousel as given in https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel

But the thing is I want to change the image to the images I have locally available in my system.

So, how can I achieve this?

This is the HTML part of my carousel code.

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div style="height: 500px">
        <uib-carousel active="active" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
            <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
                <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            </uib-slide>
        </uib-carousel>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller code:

```
angular.module('portfolioApp', ['ngAnimate','ngTouch','ui.bootstrap'])
 .controller('HomeController', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.myInterval = 5000;
    $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
    $scope.active = 0;
    var slides = $scope.slides = [];
    var currIndex = 0;

    $scope.addSlide = function() {
        var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
        slides.push({
            image: 'http://lorempixel.com/' + newWidth + '/480',
            text: ['Nice image','Awesome photograph','That is so cool','I love that'][slides.length % 4],
            id: currIndex++
        });
    };

    $scope.randomize = function() {
        var indexes = generateIndexesArray();
        assignNewIndexesToSlides(indexes);
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        $scope.addSlide();
    }

    // Randomize logic below

    function assignNewIndexesToSlides(indexes) {
        for (var i = 0, l = slides.length; i < l; i++) {
            slides[i].id = indexes.pop();
        }
    }

    function generateIndexesArray() {
        var indexes = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < currIndex; ++i) {
            indexes[i] = i;
        }
        return shuffle(indexes);
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802#962890
    function shuffle(array) {
        var tmp, current, top = array.length;

        if (top) {
            while (--top) {
                current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
                tmp = array[current];
                array[current] = array[top];
                array[top] = tmp;
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Where exactly are the images you want to show? Are they on same machine as the browser running the web app?

Comment: I want to replace the url and I have my own images in the same directory within my web application's directory. I want to use those images in my carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each image you want to add, call

`slides.push({
   image: image_filename,
   text: image_text,
   id: currIndex++
});`

where image_filename is the filename of the image and image_text is the text you want to print over the image

Comment: I want to add html page using ng-include in slide instead of an image. Any idea how I can push html page in slides?