# How does this W3Schools code for shuffling an array with .sort() work?

Tags: javascript

This code snippet is from [w3schools JavaScript section](https://www.w3schools.com/js/). I am trying to figure out what

```
points.sort( function(a, b) {
  return 0.5 - Math.random()
});
```

from the code below does. I understand it is trying to perform a random sort on the numbers stored in the array called points, but I don't understand how it is achieved with `return 0.5 - Math.random()`.

I know that random returns a number between 0 and 1 (not including 1). 
I supposed that 0.5 is then subtracted from that number, but I am not sure what happens from here. Could you kindly give me a step by step explanation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <p>Click the button (again and again) to sort the array in random order.</p>

   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

   <p id="demo"></p>

   <script>
     var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;    

     function myFunction() {
      points.sort(function(a, b){return 0.5 - Math.random()});
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;
     }
   </script>

 </body>
```

Comment: sort callback function returns `-n`, `0` or `+n` depending on the comparison between `a` and `b` - using a random value from -0.5 to +0.5 will basically shuffle the array randomly

Comment: [This is a horrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/962802/1048572).

Answer (score 3):

Passing a callback to `Array#sort()` that returns a random value is a bad idea; the ECMAScript spec provides no guarantees about what will happen in that case. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

And per [the spec itself](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort):

> If *comparefn* is not **undefined** and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), the sort order is implementation-defined.

The W3Schools code from the question is demonstrably broken; it doesn't shuffle the array fairly, at least in Chrome. Let's try running it a million times and counting how often each value shows up in the final position in the array after "shuffling":

```
function shuffleAndTakeLastElement() {
    var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
    return points.sort(function(a, b){return 0.5 - Math.random()})[5];
}
results = {};
for (var point of [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10]) results[point] = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) results[shuffleAndTakeLastElement()]++;
console.log(results);
```

I get the following counts in Chrome:

```
{1: 62622, 5: 125160, 10: 500667, 25: 249340, 40: 31057, 100: 31154}
```

Notice how the number 10 is around 16 times more likely to end up in the end position of the array than the numbers 40 or 100 are. This ain't a fair shuffle!

A few morals to draw from this story:

- You should run a large number of tests and look at the results to help confirm whether any randomness algorithm is fair.
- It's easy to accidentally write a biased algorithm even if you're starting with a fair source of randomness.
- For shuffling arrays, use [Lodash's `_.shuffle` method](https://lodash.com/docs/#shuffle) or one of the approaches from [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/1709587).
- Never trust anything you read on W3Schools, because they suck and are riddled with errors.

Comment: See also http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html as a backup reference

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` callback is supposed to return a value <0, 0 or >0 to indicate whether the first value is lower than, equal to or higher than the second; `sort` uses that to sort the values. `0.5 - Math.random()` returns a value between -0.5 and 0.5 randomly, satisfying the expected return values and resulting in an essentially randomly shuffled array.

Note that this shouldn't be the preferred method to shuffle; since the return value is random and not internally consistent (e.g. it tells `sort` that `foo < bar`, `bar < baz` and `foo > baz`), it may make Javascript's sort algorithm very inefficient. A [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for instance is pretty trivially implemented and likely more efficient.

Comment: Efficiency is one consideration, sure. But probably more importantly, the W3Schools shuffle violates the ECMAScript spec and is horribly biased when run on real implementations - see the test in my answer.

Comment: Not just inefficient, but also [simply incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2359667/1048572).