# What are the disadvantages of my shuffle function?

Tags: javascript

After reading through some "how to shuffle" questions on SO, I saw that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling/962829#962829) was generally accepted:

```
function shuffle (array) {
    var tmp, current, top = array.length;

    if(top) while(--top) {
        current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
        tmp = array[current];
        array[current] = array[top];
        array[top] = tmp;
    }

    return array;
}
```

But what would the problems be with just picking the elements in the list randomly, [like I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45401681/4576519):

```
function shuffle (array) {
  var result = [];
  while(array.length){
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    result.push(array.splice(index, 1)[0]);
  }  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Your index might not be unique everytime

Comment: @Durga That doesn't matter though. It's splicing the value so it's not going to be selected after it is

Comment: This is a really great explanation, which includes your method: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the result given by your answer, it does seem to shuffle the array as you pick up a random index and then push it to the resulting array.

The difference between the two approaches is of efficiency, the first solution has a worst case time complexity of O(n) and your solution has a worst case time complexity of O(n^2) as splice has a worst case complexity of O(n) and there is a while loop taking O(n), also the second approach has a space complexity of O(n).

Comment: Thankyou. You're answer made me realize that the two shuffle functions in the questions are remarkably similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `.slice()` on original array before `while` loop to preserve the original array.

```
function shuffle (array) {
  var result = [];
  var temp = array.slice(0);
  while(temp.length){
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * temp.length);
    result.push(temp.splice(index, 1)[0]);
  }  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: A disadvantage is efficiency. I'm not sure splicing is the best operation here; it's definitively not as efficient as the former I would think.

Comment: @AndrewLi We can avoid speculation by creating benchmarks for each approach

Comment: Well the time complexity of each approach speaks for itself. Splicing is O(n), so iterating and splicing would be O(n * n). Just a while loop and array access would be O(n * 1).

Comment: @AndrewLi Am still not versed in time complexity verbage. That is one area where this user needs to invest more time in fully gathering the principles. Will remove the first sentence from Answer.

Comment: @AndrewLi Curious what the time complexity is of an approach using `.forEach()` and `setTimeout()` https://jsfiddle.net/jyqo9ego/?

Comment: Still O(n). The function will only ever iterate N times, where N is directly proportional for any input X which is the array length.

Comment: @AndrewLi Found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm. Am still reading the answers trying to grasp the concept.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is that while your solution constructs a new `result` array, it also empties the argument `array` which is an absolute bad practise. Don't mutate your arguments unnecessarily. Also, using `splice` is pretty inefficient as it moves around all elements after the removed one.