# Sorting an Array in Random Order

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, random

I'm trying to understand how sorting an array in random order works. So, I found the following code:

```js
var as = ["max","jack","sam"];  
var s = as.sort(func);  

function func(a, b) {  
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
}  

console.log(s);
```

my main question is why they use **0.5 not another number**?
and **how it really works**

Comment: Why you passed `func` into your `sort()` function for sorting an array of string ?

Comment: @KolaCaine Becuase [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) take a sort function?

Comment: Yes, you can passed a callback function. But what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: terminologically it's not `sorting` but `shuffling` using `sort` function

Comment: also please refer to the answer from the question @ponury-kostek linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650169/3729695

Comment: This is a bad idea - the sort predicate should be consistent. If for whatever reason you compare `a` and `b` twice, the result should be the same. And in general, it should also consistent. (So a<b and b<c imply a<c, or a>b and b>c imply a>c - the choice of order is independent from the need for consistency)

Comment: "*how it really works?*" - [it **doesn't work** at all!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/962802/1048572) See also http://robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html

Comment: @ponury-kostek Personally, I think that this one's closer, since the question's asking how this particular one works, not how it should be done.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You used

```
var as = ["max","jack","sam"];  
var s = as.sort(func);  

function func(a, b) {  
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
}  

console.log(s);
```

And **here the most important thing** is `as.sort(func)`.
`func(a,b)` will return value in range of `[-0.5,0.5]`.

Because this function return `0.5 - Math.random()` and `Math.random()` will return the float value which is in range of `[0,1]`.
So that your `func` will return value in range of `[-0.5,0.5]`.

And this mean that sort order will be set `increase` or `decrease`.
this is random.
So your result will be random

```js
var as = ["max","jack","sam"];  
var s = as.sort(func);  

function func(a, b) {  
  return Math.random();
}  

console.log(s);
```

```js
var as = ["max","jack","sam"];  
var s = as.sort(func);  

function func(a, b) {  
  return 0 - Math.random();
}  

console.log(s);
```

```js
var as = ["max","jack","sam"];  
var s = as.sort(func);  

function func(a, b) {  
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
}  

console.log(s);
```

Comment: Crucially, a value of `0.5` makes the probability that one element is evaluated to be less than another exactly 1/2, which makes the random sort unbiased with respect to the initial order of the list.

Comment: @BallpointBen That's simply wrong. [Using `Math.random()` in `sort` does not lead to unbiased results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896494/1048572).

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I'm leaving my comment anyway so that others can see the error

Comment: Actually, Math.random() method will return 0 to less than 1. Not 0 to 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 14):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number between `0` and `1` (exclusive). We're using `0.5` because it is the **mean value**.

[`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts the parameters based on the **return value**. So, `0.5 - Math.random()` will yield *either positive or negative value with equal probability*. Hence, it will sort the parameters *randomly*.

#### How it really works

- If the return value of `Array.sort()` is **positive**, then the index of the
  first parameter will be *higher* than that of the second.
- If it is **negative**, then the index of the second parameter will be
  *higher* than that of the first.
- And, if it is `0`, then *do nothing*.

Answer (score 6):

**Math.random()** return random value between ***0 to 1 (0 is included but 1 is excluded)***.
So 0.5 act as mid point. If use use value like greater than 1 or less 0 than it will always be either true or false.
So for this reason 0.5 is used.

### You can read more here about Math.random()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

> Let's understand it bit more with examples

```js
var as = ["max","jack","sam"];  
var s = as.sort(func);  

function func(a, b) {  
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
}  

console.log(s);
```

***This is what you get when you use value greater than 1***

```js
var as = ["max","jack","sam"];  
var s = as.sort(func);  

function func(a, b) {  
  return 1 - Math.random();
}  

console.log(s);
```

***This is what happens when you use value less than 0***

```js
var as = ["max","jack","sam"];  
var s = as.sort(func);  

function func(a, b) {  
  return -1 - Math.random();
}  

console.log(s);
```

***P.S*** :-

1. Try printing output from all the above condition you will see that last two condition will always return either true or false from function. so you will not get a random sorting.
2. Now talk about any value from 0 to 0.99 you can use any value but 0.5 will serve your purpose best.Because it's a middle point you're most likely to get best answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to nudge the elements near their starting positions in a random way, sure, use `sort` with `random`, but in most cases, that's not what you want. You want to thoroughly shuffle an array, completely randomize the position of every element. And for that `random` in the built-in `sort` function is a terrible practice, because it is biased towards the initial state, meaning that the elements in the "shuffled" array will tend to stay near their positions (those that were near the beginning have the high probability of staying near the beginning, etc...). The bigger the size the array grows, the less it gets shuffled.

Here is the proof: [Is it correct to use JavaScript Array.sort() method for shuffling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling/19896494#19896494)

And here is the function for shuffling arrays I use most of the time. It thoroughly randomizes the position of every element.

```
function shuffle(arr) { // randomly rearanges the items in an array
  const result = [];
  for (let i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // picks an integer between 0 and i:
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));   // NOTE: use a better RNG if cryptographic security is needed
    // inserts the arr[i] element in the r-th free space in the shuffled array:
    for(let j = 0, k = 0; j <= arr.length-1; j++) {
      if(result[j] === undefined) {
        if(k === r) {
          result[j] = arr[i];    // NOTE: if array contains objects, this doesn't clone them! Use a better clone function instead, if that is needed. 
          break;
        }
        k++;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random` returns a number between 0 and 1.

Sorting function use the return value `x` as the following :

- `x == 0` : Same value, can order "how it wants"
- `x < 0` : the first object is **less than** the second one, therefore its index in the sorted array will be less than the other's
- `x > 0` same as `x < 0` but the other way around

Since `Math.random` returns a number between 0 and 1 and we want to also get negative numbers, we must subtract some value. 
Here `0.5 - Math.random()` would give a number between 0.5 and -0.5

Answer (score 1):

## Shortest Form (Using Lambda Expression):

To answer the question "How sorting of an array in random order works", as others have mentioned, the Array.sort() function can take a function as parameter.

**Syntax**:

```
Array.sort([sort_by_function()])
```

The inner `sort_by_function()` accepts two parameters (e.g.: x & y) and with use of `Math.random()` returns a value between -0.5 to 0.5, it returns:

- Negative number (-0.5 to -0.1), if x < y
- Zero (0), if x = y Positive
- Positive number (0.1 to 0.5), if x > y

Remember, if you don't pass in anything to the outer `Array.sort()` function, it simply rearranges/sorts the elements in *Ascending* order, if however, you pass in a function (as argument), then it behaves based on what the inner `sort_by_function()` returns, as it swaps EACH Element of the given array (by swapping pair of two elements at-a-time) essentially, this swapping is decided based on what the inner `sort_by_function()` returned.

To achieve random-sort order the `Array.sort()` function will rearrange/sort each pair of elements as below, for a:

- Negative value: swap in ascending order,
- Zero: no change,
- Positive value: swap in descending order.

**Example**:

```
arr.sort(function(x,y){return Math.random() - 0.5});
```

As no one mentioned about the use of the short Lambda expression, here is an example on how you can shorten the inner parameter-function by use of the Lambda expression as below:

```
arr.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call the `sort` method with a function parameter is called several times. This function should accept two parameters (let's call the first A and the second B) Each time it should return a value:

1. Less than zero, if `A < B`
2. Equal to zero, if `A = B`
3. Greater the zero, if `A > B`

So in this example we need random return values that evenly distribute negative and positive values. Since `Math.random()` returns a value between 0 and 1, `0.5 - Math.random()` will return values between -0.5 and 0.5, which meets the requirements.