# Order by random a list of div elements with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have a category that contains more than 200 newsitems, on the homepage I display the last 20 newsitems.

```
<div class="container-category">
   <div class="col-3">item 1</div>
   <div class="col-3">item 2</div>
   <div class="col-3">item 3</div>
   <div class="col-3">item 4</div>
   <div class="col-3">item ..n</div>
</div>
```

How to make the list of `<div class="col-3">` appear randomly with Javascript ?

`OrderBy = random`

Comment: You should order them on your server, not on the client.

Comment: On the backend not possible, I can only order them with `datetime` or `title` but not with random

Comment: What backend you are using? php?

Comment: This tecnique could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591691/sorting-an-array-in-random-order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal way to shuffle the categories is through the backend. But incase you can't, we can borrow the [shuffle functionality here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/2930661).

Use jQuery `get()` to get the array of category divs. Use the function to shuffle the array and use `html()` to update the content.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

var categories = shuffle($(".container-category>div").get());
$(".container-category").html(categories);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-category">
  <div class="col-3">item 1</div>
  <div class="col-3">item 2</div>
  <div class="col-3">item 3</div>
  <div class="col-3">item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works exactly as I've been looking for. Thanks @Eddie

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Here I show a variant of Eddie's answer that works without jQuery. The [shuffle function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/2930661):

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
```

We can utilize this to shuffle the div's children as follows:

```
// Get the DOM object of the parent div
const container = document.querySelector('.container-category');

// Turn container.children, which is an HTMLCollection, into an array
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/222847 for more on this
const children = [...container.children];

// The shuffle function above mutates the argument, so here we shuffle
// the array of children; note that this is not yet reflected in the DOM
shuffle(children);

// Reinsert the children to the parent according to the new order
for (const child of children) {
    container.appendChild(child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was shuffling of array items but you have the answer also I guess it works slower with big arrays. So I made another solution:

```js
    function getRandIndex(arrayLen) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLen);
    }
    
    function getRandUniqueIndexes(arrayLen, count) {
      const indexes = [];

      while (indexes.length < count) {
        const randIndex = getRandIndex(arrayLen);

        if (!indexes.includes(randIndex)) {
          indexes.push(randIndex);
        }
 
      }

      return indexes;
    }

    // your array with 200 categories
    const categories = Array(200).fill(1).map((_, ndx) => `category-${ndx}`);
    // array with 20 random unique indexes
    const rand20Indexes = getRandUniqueIndexes(categories.length, 20);

    console.log(rand20Indexes.map(catIndex => categories[catIndex]));
```