# Can I use array.filter() to get sample elements from array?

Tags: javascript, statistics, combinations

I am learning JavaScript and trying to apply it in statistical sampling.
The function below does not work but assumes:

- array = population to study
- sample = sample drawn from population
- element = each observation from population

```
const generateSample = array => {
    var sample = []
    array.filter(element => {
            (element in sample) ? return null : sample = [...sample, element]
    })
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with any data?

Comment: No. The function does not work. I am trying to use the filter method as it seems less verbose and descriptive. I also realized i need to add sample size to the equation

Comment: Why you want to use `filter` for such cases, use `forEach` or any loop, filter should be used without any side-effects

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're trying to do here. [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes in a predicate function that's run over every element in the array. It returns an array made of each element for which the predicate results in `true`.

If you're trying to achieve something similar to Python's slice notation, look at [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: If array = [1,2,3,4,5] and size = 2, the result could be [3,1] or [2,4], and not [2,2]. I thought filter checks a condition of whether the randomly selected element is in the sample

Comment: but `filter` can't be stopped at size2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to use JavaScript Array.sort() method for shuffling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling)

Comment: Yes. I tested Array.sort() but it seems to mutate the original array. I should probably read on Fisher-Yates shuffle and try to write it in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, this is what i found when retrieving a sample of size N from an array

1. Shuffle the array
2. Slice the shuffled array to get sample of size N

**NOTE:** The `shuffleArray` function was created with the help of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/12993865)
 and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46161940/12993865)

Below are the two functions that solved the problem

```js
// Function that shuffles an array
const shuffleArray = array => {
  if (array.length === 1) return array

  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  const randomElement = array[randomIndex]

  array = array.filter((_, i) => i !== randomIndex)

  return [randomElement, ...shuffleArray(array)];
};

// Function that returns sub array from array
const subArray = (array, n) => array.slice(0, n)

const population = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const shuffled = shuffleArray(population)
console.log( shuffled )
console.log(subArray(shuffled, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.filter` expects a function that returns `true` or `false` (whether to keep the element in the array). The function you give to `filter` returns null... or doesn't return at all. `(element in array)` will check if array.length >= element as the `in` operator checks if a property is in an object or its prototype chain. To check if an element is in an array use `.includes()` or `.indexOf() >= 0`. Also the ternary operator `condition ? expr : expr` expects expressions, not statements like `return null` or `sample =`

Maybe something like?

```js
let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let sample = data.filter(() => Math.round(Math.random()));

console.log(sample);
```

Comment: Ok. I edited my code and meant (element in sample) to check if randomly selected element is in sample array