# How to stop loading images in angularjs carousel

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

For performance improvemnt, in my application we are using charts as carousel. So it is takeing more time to rendering qlik charts. I want to load only the first image(chart) and need to stop loading the remaining all.

- I have only 3 charts in the carousel. It is always 3 only.
- For first time while loading page, it must be in the first image. So the first image only should load. Remaining 2nd and 3rd images should not get load.
- After click on the next button only, i need to load the second image. At that time do not load on the third image.
- Again after click on third image, the third image only should get load.

These three charts datas I am getting from API. How can I achieve this.

Please look at the follwing plunkr for sample with all datas loading.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ozgym2aMsJEsVlmF?preview)

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 5000;
  $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
  $scope.active = 0;
  var slides = $scope.slides = [];
  var currIndex = 0;

  $scope.addSlide = function() {
    var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
    slides.push({
      image: '//unsplash.it/' + newWidth + '/300',
      text: ['Nice image','Awesome photograph','That is so cool','I love that'][slides.length % 4],
      id: currIndex++
    });
  };

  $scope.randomize = function() {
    var indexes = generateIndexesArray();
    assignNewIndexesToSlides(indexes);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $scope.addSlide();
  }

  // Randomize logic below

  function assignNewIndexesToSlides(indexes) {
    for (var i = 0, l = slides.length; i < l; i++) {
      slides[i].id = indexes.pop();
    }
  }

  function generateIndexesArray() {
    var indexes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < currIndex; ++i) {
      indexes[i] = i;
    }
    return shuffle(indexes);
  }

  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802#962890
  function shuffle(array) {
    var tmp, current, top = array.length;

    if (top) {
      while (--top) {
        current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
        tmp = array[current];
        array[current] = array[top];
        array[top] = tmp;
      }
    }

    return array;
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
  <div style="height: 305px">
    <div uib-carousel active="active" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
      <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Slide {{slide.id}}</h4>
          <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me how can I do this using angularjs.

Comment: Quick win will be to add `loading="lazy"` attribute to the `img` tag - https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr

Comment: Where are your prev(), next() and select() functions ?

Comment: @MoshFeu I tried loading="lazy". But it is not working. If 3 images loading at a time, it is impacting the performance. So i want to load 1st image only. Then after click on right arrow or bottom dots, i need to load the next image. Same for next arrow or dot. This is my question. Please update in plunkr