# Execute class methods in random order - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class, for-of-loop

I need to execute all methods in random order from main_method (i will create a class instance later).
But when first function start executing it shows that "this" inside her is equal undefined.
How can i fix this? Thx

```
class test {
 construstor(smth) {
  this.smth = smth
 }
 async main_method {
  for (let func of [this.#method1, this.#method2, this.#method3].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5 )) {
    await func(this.smth);
  }
 }
 async #method1(smth) {
 // this === undefined
  ///
 }
 async #method2(smth) {
  // this === undefined
  ///
 }
 async #method3(smth) {
  // this === undefined
  ///
 }
}
```

Comment: `await func.call(this, this.smth)`

Comment: or `var self = this` and after that `func(self.smth)`

Comment: That won't help, @IT The issue isn't that the parameter `smth` is undefined, it's `this`. Your version still invokes `func` with no context

Comment: [Do not use JavaScript Array `.sort()` method for shuffling!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/962802/1048572)