# How do I make my JavaScript slideshow play in random order?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tweaked W3Schools' [Automatic Slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto) and made my own slideshow. My slideshow pauses once the mouse is hovered over the slideshow, but resumes once the mouse moves off the slideshow.

The only thing I want to change is the order of images, I would like them to go in random order. Could anyone offer some advice to what I could do?

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandemonium_cabbage/zpjuc17a/)

JavaScript:

```
    <script>

        var myIndex = 0;

        carousel();

        function carousel() {

            var i;

            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("thewellDiv");

            myTimeout = setTimeout(carousel, 400);

            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }

            myIndex++;

            if (myIndex > x.length) { myIndex = 1 }
            x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        }

        function onMouseOver() {
            clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        }

        function onMouseOut() {
            myTimeout = setTimeout(carousel, 400);
        }

    </script>
```

HMTL:

```
    <div class="thewellContainer" id="thewellContainer">

        <div class="thewellDiv">
            <img src="/image/sun/0001.webp" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
        </div>

        <div class="thewellDiv">
            <img src="/image/sun/0002.webp" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
        </div>

        <div class="thewellDiv">
            <img src="/image/sun/0003.webp" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
        </div>

        <div class="thewellDiv">
            <img src="/image/sun/0004.webp" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
        </div>

        <div class="thewellDiv">
            <img src="/image/sun/0005.webp" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
        </div>

        <div class="thewellDiv">
            <img src="/image/sun/0006.webp" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
        </div>

        <div class="thewellDiv">
            <img src="/image/sun/0007.webp" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
        </div>

        <div class="thewellDiv">
            <img src="/image/sun/0008.webp" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
        </div>

        <div class="thewellDiv">
            <img src="/image/sun/0009.webp" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
        </div>

        <div class="thewellDiv">
            <img src="/image/sun/0010.webp" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .thewellContainer {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            font-size: 3vh;

            background: cadetblue;
        }

        .thewellDiv {
            display: none;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;

            background: yellow;
        }

        .thewellPhoto {
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 65vh;
            background-color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: In the carousel function use the `Math.random()` method to generate a random number between 0 and x.length-1 and show the according div. For more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: Do you want to be certain that every image is shown each time the system loops round?

Comment: @AHaworth I didn't think of that but that's a great point actually! Would be more intelligent if all images are shown before it starts looping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet has an array, a, of the same length as the number of images.

It starts off by putting the numbers 0-9 in it, and then shuffles them in such a way that all the numbers are always represented but the order is random.

Then each time you start the loop over the images again it reshuffles the array.

The next image to be chosen during the loop is not chosen directly through the actual myIndex, but the number that is in the array at that position.

```html
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/image/logo/V.1.png" />

  <title>
    Atomiser
  </title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .thewellContainer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      font-size: 3vh;
      background: cadetblue;
    }
    
    .thewellDiv {
      display: none;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
      background: yellow;
    }
    
    .thewellPhoto {
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 65vh;
      background-color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="thewellContainer" id="thewellContainer">

    <div class="thewellDiv">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0EIueMp.jpeg" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
    </div>

    <div class="thewellDiv">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/XgbZdeA.jpeg" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
    </div>

    <div class="thewellDiv">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jDimNTZ.jpeg" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
    </div>

    <div class="thewellDiv">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yznJhMU.jpeg" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
    </div>

    <div class="thewellDiv">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3GE0Ufo.jpeg" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
    </div>

    <div class="thewellDiv">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h0KvRJq.jpeg" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
    </div>

    <div class="thewellDiv">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/N9wuvHI.jpeg" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
    </div>

    <div class="thewellDiv">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AOuyWAR.jpeg" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
    </div>

    <div class="thewellDiv">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/H2bvxh0.jpeg" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
    </div>

    <div class="thewellDiv">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/m6hQD1G.jpeg" class="thewellPhoto" onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">
    </div>

  </div>
  <script>
    let a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) a[i] = i;

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802#962890
    function shuffle(array) {
      let tmp, current, top = array.length;
      if (top)
        while (--top) {
          current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
          tmp = array[current];
          array[current] = array[top];
          array[top] = tmp;
        }
      return array;
    }

    a = shuffle(a);
    var myIndex = 0;

    carousel();

    function carousel() {

      var i;

      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("thewellDiv");

      myTimeout = setTimeout(carousel, 800);

      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }

      myIndex++;

      if (myIndex > x.length) {
        a = shuffle(a);
        myIndex = 1
      }
      x[a[myIndex - 1]].style.display = "block";

      // COMMENTED AS IT'S NOT A LEGAL FN: document.getElementByClass("thewellContainer").style.color = "transparent";

    }

    function onMouseOver() {
      clearTimeout(myTimeout);

      document.getElementById('thewellContainer').style.background = 'rebeccapurple';

    }

    function onMouseOut() {
      myTimeout = setTimeout(carousel, 800);

      document.getElementById('thewellContainer').style.background = 'cadetblue';

    }
  </script>

</body>
```