Random Jekyll javascript carousel: how to avoid repetition in sequence?
I've been developing a very simple website with Jekyll with a random carousel on home.
I would like to avoid repetition of image before all images in the stack have been shown.
This is the code I'm using:
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
    .carousel__holder {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative; 
        margin-top: 3em;
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 1rem 0 1rem;
            }

    .carousel {
        max-width: 80%;
        max-height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        }

    .carousel__slide {
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        display: block;
        }   
            
    .carousel__slide .overlay {height: 100%;}
    .carousel--thumb .carousel__indicator {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    
<div class="carousel_holder" id="carousel_holder">
    {% assign image_files = site.static_files| where: "image", true %}
    {% for image in image_files %}
            <img src="{{ image.path }}" class="carousel" alt="image">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
    
  <script>
    let a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 85; ++i) a[i] = i;

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802#962890
    function shuffle(array) {
      let tmp, current, top = array.length;
      if (top)
        while (--top) {
          current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
          tmp = array[current];
          array[current] = array[top];
          array[top] = tmp;
        }
      return array;
    }

    a = shuffle(a);
    var myIndex = 0;

    carousel();

    function carousel() {

      var i;

      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel");

      myTimeout = setTimeout(carousel, 1800);

      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }

      myIndex++;

      if (myIndex > x.length) {
        a = shuffle(a);
        myIndex = 1
      }
      x[a[myIndex - 1]].style.display = "block";

      // COMMENTED AS IT'S NOT A LEGAL FN: document.getElementByClass("thewellContainer").style.color = "transparent";

}

    
</script>

</body>

Can you please give me some advice on how to implement thi feature on javascript?
Thank you for your help

It looks you already tried to implement this, by re-shuffling the array only when you reached the last item? So what about this isn't working like it should, exactly?

It doesn't seem so, it is showing same image twice before the end of array.

sounds like an off-by-one error? let me guess: chatgpt wrote the code?

That’s wrong. I’ve edited an existing carousel slider for Jekyll and added a random mechanic in Java script. Sure, I’m not a pro, that’s why I was looking for help. Maybe chatgpt could help though.
